# Custom group/category for the „Find Entity“ actions

Tags: swift, sirishortcuts, appintents, app-shortcut

I’ve seen that some of Apple’s apps group the automatically generated "Find XYZ" actions into custom categories. For example Safari, Calendar, or Reminders do this.

I know that you can group `AppIntents` into custom categories via:

```
static let description: IntentDescription = IntentDescription("Some Description", categoryName: "Some Category")
```

Though, the automatic "Find X" actions of an `AppEntity` are all added on top of the shortcuts list in no group.
**So, is it possible to add a custom category name to an `AppEntity`?**

#### App Examples

[image: Reminders Shortcuts]
[image: Safari Shortcuts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the „Explore enhancements to App Intents“ WWDC talk ([at 28:27](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10103?time=1707))!

Starting with iOS 17 you can add static [`findIntentDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/entitypropertyquery/findintentdescription-97u0i) var to your `EntityQuery` like this:

```
struct MyIntentQuery: EntityPropertyQuery {
    
    static var findIntentDescription: IntentDescription? {
        IntentDescription(
            "This is my intent description visible in the info sheet of the Shortcuts app.",
            categoryName: "Category Name")
    }

    // …
}
```